# Apache CXF wsdl2java InternalError: unresolved reference

Tags: web-services, cxf, wsdl2java

I'm trying to generate Java sources for a Web Service with Apache CXF wsdl2java executable (I've tried 2.7.8 and 3.2.0 versions).

My wsdl file come from an external agency ([TMDD](http://www.ite.org/standards/tmdd/3.03.asp)), so I assume is *well generated*

When I tried to generate files first time, a "Non-unique body parts" error occur:

```
org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: Non-unique body parts! In a port, operations must have unique operation signatures on the wire for successful dispatching. In port {http://www.tmdd.org/303/dialogs}tmddOCSoapHttpServicePort, operations "{http://www.tmdd.org/303/dialogs}dlVideoSwitchStatusRequest" and "{http://www.tmdd.org/303/dialogs}dlIntersectionSignalStatusRequest" have the same request body block {http://www.tmdd.org/303/messages}deviceInformationRequestMsg

    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.validate(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:735)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:276)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:412)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:105)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:185)
```

I solved it creating a new input message type in dlVideoSwitchStatusRequest operation to avoid this. My steps were:

1. Create a new message type

   `<message name="MSG_VideoSwitchStatusRequest">
       <part name="message" element="tmdd:videoSwitchStatusRequestMsg"/>
   </message>`
2. Declare videoSwitchStatusRequestMsg

   `<xs:element name="videoSwitchStatusRequestMsg" type="VideoSwitchStatusRequest">
       <xs:annotation>
           <xs:documentation>
               <objectClass>VideoSwitch</objectClass>
               <requirement>REQ1109</requirement>
           </xs:documentation>
       </xs:annotation>
   </xs:element>`

   *This one is defined in `.xsd` file as similar ones for other operations.*
3. Modify input type for that operation

   ```
   <operation name="dlVideoSwitchStatusRequest">
       <documentation><objectClass>VideoSwitch</objectClass><objectClass>ExternalCenter</objectClass><objectClass>OwnerCenter</objectClass><msgPattern>R-R</msgPattern><requirement>REQ538</requirement></documentation>
       <input message="tns:MSG_VideoSwitchStatusRequest"/>    <!-- This is the new type -->
       <!--<input message="tns:MSG_DeviceInformationRequest"/>  This is the old one --> 
       <output message="tns:MSG_VideoSwitchStatus"/>
       <fault name="errorReport" message="tns:MSG_ErrorReport"/>
   </operation>
   ```

With this, that error was solved (i think), but now i get another error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: unresolved reference
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef._get(DelayedRef.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef$Type.getType(DelayedRef.java:148)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.ElementDecl.getType(ElementDecl.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.ElementDecl.updateSubstitutabilityMap(ElementDecl.java:174)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.getResult(ParserContext.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.getResult(XSOMParser.java:214)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:538)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:269)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:459)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:723)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:412)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:105)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:185)
```

This one is too generic and I didn't found any info or doc from Apache site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as B. Leal suggest, i drop old `tmdd.wsdl` and re-do my `wsdl` files with separate files for each device i will need data for.

As most work has been re-done, i'm not 100% sure about where that error came from, but i'm pretty sure that it was related with some types used in the old `wsdl` that wasn't declared properly in `xsd` files.

I know this is not a big help, but if someone falls in this same error, i think you only have two choices:

- Re-do your `wsdl` files, as i did. (I recommend this one, it's easier than it seems)
- Check if every single type used in `wsdl` are present in `xsd` files and if they're correct.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must no assume the [TMDD](http://www.ite.org/standards/tmdd/) wsdl is well generated. I worked with it some time ago and is plenty of errors.

I recommend you to re-create your own version of `TMDD.wsdl` file, limiting it only to those items you're going to use.

Try that and tell us what you got.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and mine was in XSD. Forgot to add namespace before type. tns and targetNamespace are the same url.
Before:

```
<xs:element name="getRequest" type="Request">
```

After

```
<xs:element name="getRequest" type="tns:Request">
```

This simple change in all elements using complexType/simpleType fixed the problem.