# Is there a practical way to find out which type causes "java.lang.InternalError: unresolved reference" with apache-cxf wsdl2java?

Tags: cxf, wsdl2java

I was trying to generate client classes for https://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceio.wsdl with wsdl2java and got the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: unresolved reference
        at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef._get(DelayedRef.java:73)
        at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef$Type.getType(DelayedRef.java:118)
        at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.ElementDecl.getType(ElementDecl.java:85)
        at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.ElementDecl.updateSubstitutabilityMap(ElementDecl.java:156)
        at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.getResult(ParserContext.java:111)
        at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.getResult(XSOMParser.java:184)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:479)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:240)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:67)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:445)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:711)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:259)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:156)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:402)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:105)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:184)
```

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46685507/apache-cxf-wsdl2java-internalerror-unresolved-reference), it is related to a type reference. This is a large WSDL file with many imports. Could anyone offer a tip about a practical way to
find the culprit?